# Beautiful Soup : Not JSON serializible

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to make a web scraper.
This is my program:

```
    print ("scraping {}".format(url))
    print ("scraping {}".format(url))
    url_text_data = url_obj_data.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(url_text_data,'html.parser')
    code = soup.findAll('div',{'class':'tabcontent'})

    code = soup.findAll('div',{'class':'tabcontent'})

    print ("code = {}".format(code))
    return code
```

When I run it it shows an error :

```
is not JSON serializable
```

I have tried using `return json.dumps(code)` but with no luck.
Please help me.

Comment: Please add the full error traceback to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Please convert the 'code' to json serializable format

```
json_data = json.dumps(list(code))
```

May be this will work..

Comment: No, it won't. `code` is a string. `list(string)` will give you list of characters.

Answer (score 0):

Please add the "code" to your question. Or

May be you need `demjson.decode(code)`

Comment: Will you please elaborate a little bit?

Comment: I tried `demjson.decode(code)` but it showed an error-
`demjson.JSONDecodeError: a Unicode decoding error occurred`